# Excel VBA to copy entire sheet and paste as values

Tags: excel, vba

I am needing to create a VBA statement that will Copy the entire active sheet and then paste as values - seems pretty simple but I am not familiar with VBA - it would essentially be automating the 'click' in the top left and copy --> paste as values.  here is what I am trying:

```
Sub CopyPasteSheetAsValues()
'Copy and Paste Summary Sheet as Values
Sheets("Summary Build").Cells.Copy
Sheets("Summary Build").Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValue
End Sub
```

Comment: This question is out of scope of SO for being too broad (as I am sure you may already know, given your reputation points). See [ask] for more information .... that said, `ws.usedrange.value = ws.usedrange.value` may be very handy (if there are no merged cells).

Comment: thanks, yeah I realized that right after I posted it!

Comment: Record Macro should help you.

Comment: I have updated the question with the vba I thought would work but I am getting the error "paste special method of range class failed" not sure what to make of it it seemed simple enough.  thanks.

Comment: one more note - what I put above does copy the entire sheet, it appears to fail at the paste portion

Comment: That's because you are missing an "s" at the end...`xlPasteValues`

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's because pasting an *entire sheet's* data is too taxing.  Is your data formatted in a table (or at least orderly)? Just create a range of your data, and copy/paste.

Comment: thanks all for the reply - the below worked...must be a monday - I appreciate the help

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You miss an s in xlPasteValues. Also, good to add Application.CutCopyMode = False to avoid the marching ants around your copy area.

```
Sub CopyPasteSheetAsValues()
    'Copy and Paste Summary Sheet as Values
    Sheets("Summary Build").Cells.Copy
    Sheets("Summary Build").Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```