# Copy all active cells and paste values in new worksheet + same formating

Tags: excel, vba

I've tried different scripts from different sources but I haven't found any that actually works.

As the title says, I'm looking for a script that copies all the visible rows/columns into a new .xlsx file, while maintaining the format and column sizes, pasting the values only.

This should be doable right?

Comment: Everything* is doable. Do you want to handle the hidden cells as if they weren't there, or as blank spaces, for the purpose of where to position the output data?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something more than:

```
Sub copyToNew()
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Workbooks.Add
Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
End Sub
```

Comment: This works but I also need to keep the same cells formatting, rows and columns size, etc.

Comment: You say that you want to maintain formatting, **pasting the values only**. I read that as if you want to maintain formatting in the new sheet, pasting values only. If you only want to paste normally, with all the formatting, you can use `xlPasteAll` instead of `xlPasteValues`

Comment: Apologies for the misunderstanding.
I need the formulas to be pasted as values, but I also need to keep the same format, I believe it should be something like 'Paste Special > Values & Source Formatting'?

Comment: None of the paste options do that, and you can't combine the options. So unfortunately you end up having to paste twice.

Comment: Use `xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats` ... refer [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlpastetype)

Comment: @Naresh That doesn't copy formatting and column size though.

Comment: Oh the OP is looking for range and column formatting.. got it wrong from OP's comment above :)

Comment: I wasn't expecting it to be so hard to show what I'm looking for.
So, I need the values instead of the formulas and I need to keep the format of the cells (colour, font, type) AND also the width and height of the columns and rows.
Isn't it possible to first paste formatting ONLY, and after paste the values for example?
Column and row width/height I can see it's more tricky, but from @Naresh refer, there's this: xlPasteColumnWidths - Copied column width is pasted.

Comment: Ok... so in theory this might also do the trick, but I do not know how to create all the steps, please let me know if you think this is possible:
(1) "Save As": Save same document as new file and .XLSX format;
(2) Delete all hidden rows/cells;
(3) Copy paste the whole sheet as "Values";

Probably I would need to keep the Save As in the end, otherwise macros are probably not enabled anymore.

Comment: If the cells are hidden due to autofilter, try replace the copy statement in this answer with Activesheet.Cells.Copy.. It's like Control+A and copy. When you filter a data and copy all the cells, not just the table all the cells in the sheet, it pastes values and formatting. You don't even need macro for that :)

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47879577/9808063) for copying all the cells in a sheet. But paste as mentioned in this answer.`Sub copyToNew()
ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
Workbooks.Add
Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub`

Comment: What in my answer is missing? You get all the formatting, like color and fonts, and all the column sizes. The only thing you aren't getting is the formulas. Wasn't that what you wanted? You can paste formatting, then width/heigt, then values, but then it's even more pasting.

Comment: Your answer is missing the final result. It's popping "Run-time error '1004': 
To do this, all the merged cells need to be the same size." This is regarding the second paste: Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Comment: Well I didn't know you had merged cells. Guess you'll have to paste one more time then. Try this.

Comment: Awesome! I had to change the order but it works perfectly! Thanks a lot. I can't vote for your answer since I don't have enough reputation, but thank you both.